# jquery.min.js error in ie6

Tags: jquery, string, slider, identifier

IE g gives me the following error:

Line: 79
Char: 4
Error: Unexpected identifier, string or number
Code: 0

The website is [test.hatc.org](http://test.hatc.org).

I am using a template that features fading images, opacity and sliding menus. I saw an error pertaining to jquery.min.js in a browser running IE8 with compatibility mode on, so I think it has something to do with that.

Any ideas or similar errors found by anyone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a trailing comma in this element:

```
$('.slider-container').cycle({
fx:'fade',
timeout:0,
speed:400,
});
```

Should be:

```
$('.slider-container').cycle({
fx:'fade',
timeout:0,
speed:400 //NO comma here
});
```

In IE8, they've changed the JScript engine to realize there is no data after the last comma - thus ignores it like other browsers.

Comment: You know, I saw the exact same trailing comma issue on another site, but of course their coding was different so I couldn't locate it. Thank you very much! One of the features of the slider still doesn't work in IE6, but the main problem has been resolved :)

Comment: no problem.  If you are still having issues with IE6 elsewhere... just post a follow up question ;-)